# deploy shinyapp.io shows error that can't find package on github

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-package, shinyapps

I write a package on github and a shiny app, I want to use shinyapp.io to run it.

But when run command deployApp(), error message shows :

```
 "The application failed to start (exited with code 1).

  Error in value[[3L]](cond) : there is no package called ‘xxxxxx’
  Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
 Execution halted"
```

the package is on github but not on CRAN.

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/lizhongliu1996/dotaRecord/blob/master/app.R) please view my code on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the RStudio functionality I got it to work. Initially I had trouble installing the dotaRecord package but once installed the publish button worked fine.

[image: shinyapps publishing]

Comment: it seems good on RStudio after , but on the shinyapp.io it still have the problem of package not find.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. I have set it up here https://elib.shinyapps.io/shinyappstest/ using RStudio.

Comment: Did it show the last two lines? Document successfully deployed to https://elib.shinyapps.io/shinyappstest/
Deployment completed: https://elib.shinyapps.io/shinyappstest/

Comment: yes, it shows successfully deployed to xxxxx, did you just install my package from github and open the app.R, then click publish?

Comment: how did u configure the shinyapp.io? just register an account and request a token and secret and input it into Rstudio, then publish the app.R?

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Is it not working for you?

Comment: I downloaded the package from GitHub, ran the app in RStudio to test and then published. I already had a shinyapps.io account set up.

Comment: I figure it out, when publish the app, just deploy the app.R file instead of deploy the whole package, then it works! Whatever, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear Mr Vader!